# PhoneGap Whitelist

Tags: cordova

I've got a PhoneGap v2.8 project that loads images and files from an external URL. I want to load the images into my pages inside PhoneGap.  I'd like to allow all images, regardless of source, but using "*.png" in the whitelist doesn't seem to work.

I can't allow the entire domain where the images are stored because other files there I want to open in the browser.  Or is there another way to force a file to open in the browser other than the whitelist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Domain Whitelist does exactly what is in its name: Domains.  It won't work for specific file types, just whole domains/subdomains.  Now as for "force a file to open in the browser", by "file" do you mean a link to another site?  or a different type of file?

Comment: My situation is that my API is hosted at one domain, and my images and other files are at a different domain.  I want the files (lets jus say a PDF) to open in the browser not in Phonegap, but the images I need to display in the application.   If I dont put the domain in the whitelist th files open as they should, but the images get blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain white-list can't be used to allow a pattern like *.png.  I had to override the behavior in code to force PhoneGap to allow all PNG files.